# Is there a PuTTY variant without modal message boxes?

Tags: putty

Basically I'm happy with PuTTY, but the behaviour with modal message boxes is driving me mad. My network connection changes a lot, and if I have say 20 putty connections open at the time, all of these start filling my screen with "Fatal error" boxes that I have to click one-by-one. All would be well if it would just say "disconnected" like it does after the box has been clicked away... To be short, I've been looking for a PuTTY variant with [this feature](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/avoid-msgbox.html) implemented. It sounds to me exactly to what I need. Is there such variant?

So far, I've been through at least [puttytray](http://haanstra.eu/putty/), [nutty](http://groehn.net/nutty/), [kitty](http://kitty.9bis.com/) and [futty](http://code.google.com/p/futty/), and they all behave the same way.

Edit: I checked out Futty, [commented out some modal boxes I found](https://github.com/eis/FuTTY-nodialog) and [rebuilt it](https://github.com/eis/FuTTY-nodialog/downloads). Works the way I want. Of course it is not properly implemented, since it is not configurable and does not have any sort of intellect, so that's not a real resolution. Does the trick for me for now, though. I'll keep this open though in case someone would know of a variant that would have it.

Comment: In case anyone wants a [newer version](https://github.com/AndreKR/PuTTY-nodialog/releases/download/Development-snapshot-2015-12-14.482b4ab/putty.exe), I applied eis' changes to today's PuTTY source.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using some simple [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) scripting:

```
WaitForError:
WinWait, PuTTY Fatal Error
   WinClose
Goto, WaitForError
```

Save the above as file.ahk and run it (after installing AutoHotKey on your PC).

This script automatically closes any dialog boxes titled "PuTTY Fatal Error". It waits persistently in the tray area.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I think I'd rather see the message in case something else causes the failure... and as I've already have my custom build of Futty, I have it solved up to a point. However, if there's a putty variant someone else maintains I'd move to that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround, but you could install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) and use the [local terminal version of putty](https://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/), then use ssh from the cygwin command line.

Comment: Yes, and there are some other ssh apps as well that I could use. But I'd be interested to know if there is a PuTTY variant or similar, since I've grown to like it.

Comment: Unless you really liked the key and connection handling in putty, I'm not sure which parts of Putty you'd miss out on.

Comment: As a side note - I can use ssh in Cygwin without the puttycyg also, I don't think it adds anything, or maybe I missed something?

Comment: Well, in addition to liking it, I have put a lot of work into my PuTTY settings, there are proxies, logging, autocommands, X11 forwards, translations for tens of servers. I don't really look forward to reimplementing those. I think if I don't find any other solutions, I'll give a try at recompiling putty with the modal box commented out.

Comment: My mistake, I assumed the terminal emulation in Putty was the important part, not the ssh client part.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Ingle successfully compiled his own version with just this change, and documented the whole process.

https://www.confidantmail.org/wordpress/index.php/2020/04/05/putty-ssh-client-eliminate-modal-fatal-error-pop-up/

Comment: yeah, that's what I did in my question as well - note there is link to github repository with source code for this, as well as downloadable executable.

Comment: OK, missed that. Also, I'm not sure why you choosed to base your work on FuTTY by then (2012), but still using such an old and out of sync fork as of today might not a good idea security-wise.

Comment: yes, it is indeed old by now. I mainly operate with machines that are mostly not connected to open internet though so it's a bit lesser concern.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Putty as ssh-session manager mostly, you can try to use Plink with Putty-session unstead, and in order to avoid modal-windows - TortoisePlink